# Stopping reputation gain on duplicate trivial question's answer?

Tags: support, reputation, specific-answer, community-wiki

The question [[this answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603167/1344955) is posted under *(by me)* is a duplicate, and I think I earned too much reputation for answering a duplicate question which I didn't know was a duplicate at that time. Is there a way to change the answer to Community Wiki, since the answer might still contain useful information, and I don't want to delete it, I just want to prevent earning even more reputation for it.

Comment: *cough* award bounties to great contributions *cough*

Comment: You made your post in good faith, not knowing it was a duplicate. People find your post helpful. What exactly is the problem here?